# Sorting ArrayList With Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array list called myfoods. In a for loop , I retrieve data from firebase and place it into the array list. Then i display everything it in a recyclerview.

```
for (DataSnapshot ing : postSnapshot.child("foods").getChildren()) {

    String name = ing.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
    String quantity = ing.child("quantity").getValue(String.class);
    String productId = ing.child("productId").getValue(String.class);     

    AllOrders order = new AllOrders(productId, name, quantity);

    myfoods.add(order);

}
```

This is my recycler view.

[image]

What I want to achieve is , group the quantity of the foods which have the same productId. Take an example for the 1st and 2nd item in the recyclerview.They have the same productId and I want to merge them into one and adding their quantity all along. Any help on how to do that ? I tried some if else statement but in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `HashMp<String, AllOrders>` containing `productId` as key and `AllOrders` as value so use

```
Map<String,AllOrder> map = new HashMap<>();
for (DataSnapshot ing : postSnapshot.child("foods").getChildren()) {

    String name = ing.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
    String quantity = ing.child("quantity").getValue(String.class);
    String productId = ing.child("productId").getValue(String.class);     

    AllOrders order = map.get(productId);
    if(order == null){ 
        // add new item, no order exists with productId
        order = new AllOrders(productId, name, quantity);
        map.put(productId,order);
    }else{ // change the value of already existing item
        String oldQ = order.getQuantity();
        int newQ = Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()) + Integer.parseInt(quantity);
        oder.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newQ));
    }

}

// whenever you need a list
myfoods = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

---

I believe you can simply get your AllOrder object directly as

```
Map<String,AllOrder> map = new HashMap<>();
for (DataSnapshot ing : postSnapshot.child("foods").getChildren()) {


    // String name = ing.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
    // String quantity = ing.child("quantity").getValue(String.class);
    // String productId = ing.child("productId").getValue(String.class);     
    AllOrder entry = ing.getValue(AllOrder.class);
    AllOrders order = map.get(entry.gerProductId());
    if(order == null){ 
        // add new item, no order exists with productId
        map.put(productId,entry);
    }else{ // change the value of already existing item
        String oldQ = order.getQuantity();
        int newQ = Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()) + Integer.parseInt(quantity);
        oder.setQuantity(String.valueOf(newQ));
    }

}

// whenever you need a list
myfoods = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 mDatabase.orderByKey().equalTo("value", "key")
```

you could change `orderByKey()` to `orderByChild("child")`

I haven't tried, but I think it will work for you.

Give it a try :))

Goodluck !

**Update:**

```
 String lastChild = "";
 mDatabase.orderByChild("productId").addChildEventListener(){

 @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, 
          @Nullable String s) {
         Object yourObject = dataSnapshot.getValue(Object.class);
         if(!TextUtils.equal(yourObject.productId(), lastChild )) {
           lastChild = yourObject.productId();
         } else {
            // Merge here
         }
    }
```

Comment: I think the OP is more looking for how to group items with the same productId.

Comment: We can merge them into one then.

Answer (score 1):

query ordered by `productId` ...and then sort into an `ArrayList` (in order to group):

```
final ArrayList<Product> orderItems = new ArrayList<Product>();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = reference.child("foods").orderByChild("productId");

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot product : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String name = product.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
                Integer quantity = product.child("quantity").getValue(Integer.class);
                Integer productId = product.child("productId").getValue(Integer.class); 

                /* room for improvement here, just to provide an idea */
                if(orderItems.get(productId) == null) {
                    /* add the product */
                    orderItems.set((int) productId), product.getValue(Product.class))
                } else {
                    /* increment the product's quantity */
                    orderItems.get(productId)).incrementQuantityBy(quantity);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

... while it might be rather practical, to already group items with the same `productId`, before even adding or updating them into Firebase - because noSQL features no `SUM()` & `GROUP BY` domain aggregate functions, which just leads to some more records and the calculation per order item.